# Get index of post

Tags: php, wordpress, function, custom-post-type

Is it possible to get the index/item key of a post, based on the order I've inserted them in the admin backend?

e.g. there are a couple of Posts, 1-100, in the backend and I need a number that I can render, so the user can see which is the oldest and newest page.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using a custom field. Create a custom field ( for example with the name "post_number") and then you can sort the site posts ( and get the index ) using the following code:

```
$posts = get_posts([
  'post_type'        => 'post',
  'post_status'      => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'   => -1, // Show all posts
  'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'            => 'DESC',
  'meta_key'         => 'post_number',
]);
```